# Why is the Jenkins .war file failing to install via command line with error TangoProject-License.url (Access is denied)?

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to install Jenkins using the .war file approach but it fails on every attempt.

I'm using:

- Windows 10 Professional
- Administrative privileges
- OpenJDK version "11.0.2" 2019-01-15/ OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9) and have the JAVA_HOME environment variable set

I have done the following:

1. Downloaded the Jenkins 2.303.1 LTS .war file
2. Placed the .war file in the following location 'C:\Tools'
3. Have opened CMD using admin settings
4. Changed directory to the 'C:\Tools' directory
5. Run the following command: 'java -jar jenkins.war'

I get the following error output:

```
C:\Tools>java -jar jenkins.war
Running from: C:\Tools\jenkins.war
webroot: $user.home/.jenkins
2021-09-03 23:31:25.531+0000 [id=1]     INFO    org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log#initialized: Logging initialized @681ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.JavaUtilLog
2021-09-03 23:31:25.596+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Beginning extraction from war file
2021-09-03 23:31:27.938+0000 [id=1]     INFO    winstone.Logger#logInternal: Jetty shutdown successfully
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sb\.jenkins\war\images\TangoProject-License.url (Access is denied)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:299)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:84)
        at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
        at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:174)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)
2021-09-03 23:31:27.944+0000 [id=1]     SEVERE  winstone.Logger#logInternal: Container startup failed
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\sb\.jenkins\war\images\TangoProject-License.url (Access is denied)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:298)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:237)
        at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:187)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.getWebRoot(HostConfiguration.java:299)
        at winstone.HostConfiguration.<init>(HostConfiguration.java:84)
        at winstone.HostGroup.initHost(HostGroup.java:66)
        at winstone.HostGroup.<init>(HostGroup.java:45)
        at winstone.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:174)
        at winstone.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:369)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at Main._main(Main.java:375)
        at Main.main(Main.java:151)

C:\Tools>
```

Post comments:

- I'm able to install Jenkins using the Windows.exe and it starts without issue
- I have OneDrive running but I do not think this is relevant to the issue

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

**Solution**: AVG Security Suite was the culprit. If you disable it and use the Windows firewall, Jenkins will successfully install.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: AVG Security Suite was the culprit. If you disable it and use the Windows firewall, Jenkins will successfully install.